# Square roots of trig polynomials: where to find proof of theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, reference-request

During a lesson in Harmonic Analysis, my professor mentioned the following theorem.

> **Theorem**
>
> Let $p$ be a one-variable trig polynomial. If $p$ is even and has real coefficients, then there exists a trig polynomial $q$ such that:
>
> $$p(\omega)=q(\omega)\overline{q(\omega)},$$
>
> Otherwise known as a square root of $p$.

He said this was a complicated theorem, and that I could find the proof «in the book by Ingrid Dobeshima» (or that's what the name sounded like). Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything by Googling that name, and Googling for the theorem is also unsuccessful, so I was wondering, first of all, if the name is correct, and secondly, if someone could point me to a reference with the proof, or prove the theorem in an answer. Any help?

Comment: Did he mean Ingrid Daubechies?

Comment: @Giulio Since the book in the answer has the theorem, I guess he probably did. Maybe I heard an extra "ma". Or maybe it was a "but" (in Italian "ma") so close to the name it seemed to be part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reference:

Ingrid Daubechies
"Ten Lectures on Wavelets"

page 172, Lemma 6.1.3

Link:
[Daubechies' book on google](https://books.google.de/books?id=cwdjT3CWY1kC&pg=PA174&lpg=PA174&dq=root%20of%20trigonometric%20polynomial%20Ingrid%20Daubechies&source=bl&ots=RSlPgH74Sr&sig=TtMNPJEHpweAK7CEtMwRmZ13ErE&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj25f6T9LrTAhWLiywKHcpnAJ8Q6AEIJzAB#v=onepage&q=root%20of%20trigonometric%20polynomial%20Ingrid%20Daubechies&f=false)